# Set winrm/config/service RootSDDL via powershell

Tags: powershell, winrm

I need to set the RootSDDL programmatically via powershell for winrm/config/service

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm set winrm/config/service @{RootSDDL="O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;RM)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)"}
Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help.
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

`winrm get winrm/config/service`

```
Service
    RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
    MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
    MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
    EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
    MaxConnections = 300
    MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
    AllowUnencrypted = true [Source="GPO"]
    Auth
        Basic = true [Source="GPO"]
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = false
        CredSSP = false
        CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    IPv4Filter = * [Source="GPO"]
    IPv6Filter = * [Source="GPO"]
    EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = true [Source="GPO"]
    EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = true [Source="GPO"]
    CertificateThumbprint
    AllowRemoteAccess = true [Source="GPO"]
```

### Resources

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#non-administrator-accounts
https://www.sevecek.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=280

Answer (score 0):

you may set some of the options using `Set-PSSessionConfiguration` cmdlet: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-pssessionconfiguration?view=powershell-6

Or if you are interested in winrm/config/service settings, you may browse them via WSMan provider: `cd wsmna:\localhost\service` and use `*-item` cmdlets (`Get-Item`, `Set-Item` and etc). 
If you would like to check other WSMan details in `cd wsmna:\localhost\`.

In powershell you may create a custom endpoit to connect and restrict PowerShell Language and cmdlets available. More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview?view=powershell-6

Hope it hels! 
Best regards, 
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

You have to single quote the @{stuf goes here} token. Otherwise PowerShell interprets it as a hash, which isn't what winrm wants.

winrm set winrm/config/service '@{RootSDDL="O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;RM)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)"}'